# Est-ce que l'expression « désembuage » est correcte?

Tags: expressions, néologismes

Le « désembuage » est un terme qui est employé dans le monde de l'automobile.
 - Quel crédit peut-on apporter à cette expression ?
 - Existe-t-il une alternative pour décrire ce processus ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Le préfixe *[dé-](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/d%C3%A9-)* est générateur et on peut donc considérer son ajout à un verbe comme correct.

Le plus souvent, il est sensé s'opposer au préfixe *[em-](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/em-)* comme dans *embrayer/débrayer*, *emballer/déballer*, ce qui veut dire que *débuer* aurait pu être un meilleur choix ; mais il peut aussi s'y accrocher comme dans *embourber/désembourber*.

L'usage a manifestement consacré *désembuer* plutôt que *débuer*, et à moins de se lancer dans une croisade en faveur de *débuer* (bonne chance), je pense que *désembuer* est à considérer comme parfaitement correct.

Comment: Pour [dé-](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/d%C3%A9-) on a « Il remplace parfois en- ou s'y accroche dans des formes doubles synon. : débourber /désembourber. » Ni _débourber_ ni _débuer_ ne me choquent, mais les formes en _désem-_ dominent visiblement dans l'usage autour de moi.

Comment: Tu as raison, je venais d'ailleurs de le remarquer dans la page de _dé-_ et d'éditer ma réponse en conséquence. En passant, _[débourber](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/d%C3%A9bourber)_ a une signification en plus que _[désembourber](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/d%C3%A9sembourber)_ : enlever la _bourbe_ d'un étang.

Answer (score 7):

Si le terme n'est pas nécessairement dans le dictionnaire, il est utilisé de manière officielle.

Ainsi on peut trouver le :

> Règlement (UE) n ° 672/2010 de la Commission du 27 juillet 2010 concernant les exigences pour la réception des dispositifs de dégivrage et de **désembuage** du pare-brise de certains véhicules à moteur et mettant en œuvre le règlement (CE) n ° 661/2009 du Parlement européen et du Conseil concernant les prescriptions pour l’homologation relatives à la sécurité générale des véhicules à moteur, de leurs remorques et des systèmes, composants et entités techniques distinctes qui leur sont destinés

Voir [[1](http://eur-lex.europa.eu/LexUriServ/LexUriServ.do?uri=CELEX:32010R0672%3aFR%3aNOT)]

Answer (score 2):

Cette expression est très largement répandue, il ne me vient pas à l'esprit de mot plus approprié pour décrire ce processus.